# Why is std::mutex twice as slow as CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, mutex, critical-section

std::mutex is implemented with critical sections, which is why it's much faster than OS Mutex (on Windows). However it's not as fast as a Windows CRITICAL_SECTION.

Timings just a tight loop in a single thread:

```
423.76ns ATL CMutex
 41.74ns std::mutex
 16.61ns win32 Critical Section
```

My question is what else is std::mutex doing? I looked at the source but couldn't follow it. However there were extra steps before it defers to the Crit Sec. My questions is: are these extra steps accomplishing useful? That is, what are the extra steps for; what would I miss out on by using CRITICAL_SECTION?

Also why did they call it Mutex if it's not implemented with a Mutex?

Comment: What are you timing? Creating a mutex, locking it, unlocking it, ...? As far as differences from the Win32 mutex: a Win32 mutex is a cross-process mutex. The standard only calls for a cross-thread mutex, which can be a lighter weight construct (and Windows implements with a critical section).

Comment: CMutex is implemented with a mutex, it isn't cheap.  std::mutex is built on top of the Concurrency Runtime, it is quite a chunk of code with functionality that significantly extend beyond the threading and scheduling primitives provided by the OS.  Layering is heavy, that doesn't come for free.  If a critsect serves your purpose and the overhead actually matters then just punt the problem and use it.

Comment: I was timing just lock/unlock.  I'm just curious what std::mutex does beyond crit sec. If it's useful then shouldn't I want it? If it's not useful why does it do it?  In think I'll use std::mutex but I'm just wondering what it does extra.

Comment: @Philip: Really the only advantages are: portability, and that it appears in the signature of other C++ threading functions.

Comment: Then I think "because it is cross-platform" might be the high level answer. Although I'm still curious what exactly the overhead is doing. I would guess "bookeeping"?

Comment: What compiler and library version do you use? std::mutex is cross-platform synchronization primitive and its performance depends on quality of implementation.

Comment: It appears to be integrated into a broader set of functionality, e.g., the code path goes past options for timeouts, it seems to be implementing its own scheduler, has a lock queue, etc.  Whether all of this provides any benefit if the simple mutex is all you're using is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A std::mutex provides non-recursive ownership semantics.  A CRITICAL_SECTION provides recursive semantics.  So I assume the extra layer in the std::mutex implementation is (at least in part) to resolve this difference.

Update:  Stepping through the code, it looks like std::mutex is implemented in terms of a queue and InterlockedX instructions rather than a classical Win32 CRITICAL_SECTION.  Even though std::mutex is non-recursive, the underlying code in the RTL can optionally handle recursive and even timed locks.

Comment: This sounds plausible except that std::recusive_mutex is not faster tha std::mutex in my tests. Which suggests they are both doing something to slow them down which is orthogonal to whether they are recursive or not, right?

Comment: Since it's UB to try to recursively lock a `std::mutex`, I don't see why code would be needed to "resolve the difference".

Comment: Perhaps it's debug code to detect the UB?  Was the timing done using release or debug?

Comment: This is not a valid reason because a recursive mutex satisfies all the semantics of a regular mutex, so there is no extra code needed to resolve the difference.